# How to authorize to a web server with android and the org.apache.http classes?

Tags: android, apache, http

I'm trying to authenticate to a web server from an android class with the org.apache.http.HttpClient.

How can I do this? The code for my connection is:

```
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("url");

HttpResponse response = null;

try {
    response = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
   ...
} catch (IOException e) {
   ...
}
Log.i("httptest", response.getStatusLine().toString());
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
```

**Edit**

I want to do a basic authentication with username and password

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Documentation for HttpClient can be found at the [HttpClient](https://web.archive.org/web/20100228010558/http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client/index.html) site.

You don't say what sort of authentication you are trying to use, so it is impossible to give you concrete answers. [Here are](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/httpcomponents/httpclient/branches/4.0.x/httpclient/src/examples/org/apache/http/examples/client/ClientAuthentication.java) [some tutorials](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/httpcomponents/httpclient/branches/4.0.x/httpclient/src/examples/org/apache/http/examples/client/ClientFormLogin.java) that [may match](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/httpcomponents/httpclient/branches/4.0.x/httpclient/src/examples/org/apache/http/examples/client/ClientPreemptiveBasicAuthentication.java) [your needs](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/httpcomponents/httpclient/branches/4.0.x/httpclient/src/examples/org/apache/http/examples/client/ClientPreemptiveDigestAuthentication.java).